# unable to find valid certification path to requested target with wso2 and Azure AD integration

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm getting the following error after setting up Azure AD authentication on WSO2.
"ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} - Authentication failed exception! Exception while requesting access token javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" I have imported the wso2carbon.cer to the java cacerts so how can this issue still persist?

Don't hesitate to ask me if I need to provide more information.
Any input regarding this would be appreciated.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Have u followed the steps mentioned in the doc https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-azure-active-directory-to-trust-wso2-identity-server/#configuring-azure-ad?

Comment: Hey @Inthirakumaaran,
Thank you for the suggestion. I have not seen that document so let me try and will let you know if I'm successful.